# get options values on multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JS**

```
function getLandmarks(places, stores) {
  console.log(places);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="places[]" id="places" onchange="getLandmarks(this.value, '');" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Place 1</option>
<option value="2">Place 2</option>
<option value="3">Place 3</option>
<option value="4">Place 4</option>
</select>
```

Based on the above, I am having trouble in getting the value of multiple items I selected. If I choose "Place 1", the `console.log` displays **1** which is correct. However, if I do a multiple selection the **value** of the first option that I selected is the one I always get. How can I get at least an array of the option's values? Or do I need to jQuery for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
<select name="places[]" id="places" onchange="getLandmarks($(this).val(), '');" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Place 1</option>
<option value="2">Place 2</option>
<option value="3">Place 3</option>
<option value="4">Place 4</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vDAY6/)

Comment: Didn't thought of that one-liner quick solution. Huge thanks amigo.